# How to do a Python argparse mutually required argument group

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I want to write a script that takes optional `--foo` and `--bar` arguments. It is legal to specify neither of them. It is also legal to specify both. However, specifying just `--foo` or just `--bar` should raise a command line parser error.

After I call `parser.parse_args()` I can write code to check this condition and raise the appropriate error, but is there a way already built into [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to do this, a sort of converse of [`add_mutually_exclusive_group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't that kind of grouping or builtin test, just this one `xor` test.

But it isn't hard to implement the test after parsing - provided your arguments have reasonable defaults (such as the default default `None`).

Another possibility is to define one argument `foobar` with `nargs=2` - it requires 2 values.

Yet another is to provide one or both with a good default, such that you don't really care whether the user provides both values or not.